# issue while trying to install ng bootstrap in angular

Tags: angular, angular-cli

## Update 1

I created a new project for test purposes using command `ng new project1`. Then added bootstrap package like this `ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`. Even then same problem is occurring. Why?

## About

I am using Angular CLI 13.1.3. while trying to install `ng bootstrap` I faced following error details.

Then I tried to update the angular/compiler dependency from 13.1.3 to 13.1.0 using the following commands.

```
ng uninstall angular/compiler
ng remove angular/compiler
```

but both of them are not available in command list

Would you like to suggest something?

## Error messages

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE 
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: practise1@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@13.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   @angular/compiler@"~13.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@"13.3.1" from @angular/localize@13.3.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/localize
npm ERR!   peer @angular/localize@"^13.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@12.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"12.0.1" from the root project

Comment: Yikes.. don’t try to manually just update internal angular dependencies.. that might break a lot.

Comment: I created a new project for test purposes using command `ng new project1`. Then added bootstrap package like this `ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`. Even then same problem is occurring. Why?

Comment: I suspect you have the incorrect version of ng-bootstrap. Maybe the schematic is not yet up-to-date?

Comment: I did not mention specific version of bootstrap. @angular/cli version is 13.1.3, what should be the correct version for bootstrap?

Comment: Try to create a new project in angular cli and then add ng bootstrap. you will notice that it does not allow to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following commands should work for creating a new Angular project with ng-bootstrap

```
npm i -g @angular/cli
ng new project1
cd project1
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

This will ensure you have the latest Angular CLI version before creating the project.

When you need to upgrade Angular dependencies, you can run `ng update`. This will tell you any further commands you need to run to upgrade your Angular dependencies.

At this point, your package.json file should be in a good state, and anyone else can install your project using `npm i`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71890666/compare-two-controls-value-validation would you like to answer here?